# How to set daterangepicker end date to null after apply

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a daterangepicker in my page and I have set the end date to null. How can I set enddate to null after I click on apply or no characters are selected. Any help is much appreciated thanks!

Below is my code :

HTML

```
 <input type="text" id="add" placeholder="Select a Start & End Date Here" class="form-control">
```

javascript

```
$('#add').daterangepicker({
        autoUpdateInput: false,
        "timePicker": true,
        "autoApply": true,
        "startDate": moment(),
        "endDate": null,
        locale: { 
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
        }
        }, function(start, end, label) {
                var start_date = start.toISOString();
                var end_date = end.toISOString();
                var selected_character_list = character_table.rows('.selected').data();
                if (selected_character_list.length == 0){
                    alert("Select character");
                    return
                }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE :** Just add `$('#add').data('daterangepicker').setEndDate('');` inside the if statement or at the end of the function for `apply` and it'll do the trick